# EDGE Browser - customized input type="range" value is not changing on first click on slider track

Tags: css, html, microsoft-edge

I have a created a customized range input referring [this](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/).
It's working fine on Chrome, IE and EDGE, however, there is one problem on **EDGE**.
The first click on slider track changes the thumb position but not the value. The subsequent clicks works fine.

Please open this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbj1faeu/6/) in EDGE for observing this behavior.

```
HTML: 

<input id="sel" type="range" min="5" max="100" value="50" step="5">
<h3>Slider Value: <span id="range"></span></h3>

JS:

(function () {
  var sel = document.querySelector('#sel');
  document.querySelector('#range').innerText = sel.value;
  sel.addEventListener('change', function (){
    document.querySelector('#range').innerText = sel.value;
  });
})()

CSS:

#sel {
  width:500px;
}

input[type=range] {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 margin: 18px 0;
 width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
 outline: none;
} 

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
 width: 100%;
 height: 8.4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
 background: #3071a9;
 border-radius: 1.3px;
 border: 0.2px solid #010101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
 border: 1px solid #000000;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 border-radius: 100%;
 background: #ffffff;
 cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
 background: #367ebd;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
 width: 100%;
 height: 8.4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: transparent;
 border-color: transparent;
 border-width: 16px 0;
 color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
 background: #2a6495;
 border: 0.2px solid #010101;
 border-radius: 2.6px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
 background: #3071a9;
 border: 0.2px solid #010101;
 border-radius: 2.6px;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #3071a9;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #367ebd;
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from handling the `change` event to handling `input` instead seems to fix the issue:

```
sel.addEventListener('input', function (){
    document.querySelector('#range').innerText = sel.value;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tz1mhys0/

Seems to still work fine in Chrome with that, other browsers I can’t currently test. If you find one where `input` does not work, I guess adding handlers for both events should probably not do much harm either.

Comment: It's working on Chrome, EDGE and Firefox but not IE. I think I'll have to add handler for both.